# TextView doesn't split line correctly

Tags: android, scrollview, textview, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have a problem with something that "should" work but it simply doesn't.

`TextView` inside `TableRow` does not provide line break where it should, instead this same `TextView` is the same width as `TableRow`, ignoring that one `TextView` is already there and taking some space.

Here is example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableAtTest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/firstContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="first description"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/firstText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test "
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallSize" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/secondContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="second description"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/secondText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"
                        android:text="test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 "
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallSize" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/pagerOnTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            tools:context=".TestActivity" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you look at width taken by fields `@id/firstText` and `@id/secondText` you'll see that right side of `TextView` is outside screen.

Any help would be appreciated around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, using weight sum and layout weight and setting the table width to match parent and the textview width to 0dp, so it will dynamically render:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableAtTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/firstContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="first description"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test "
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image: split text image]

Comment: I just added layout_weight of 1 to right column text views and it worked like charm. Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I did spend too much time on thisone thou :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an inner container to your `TableRow`. `TextViews` will not interact with each other unless specified in your layout.

You can add your `TextViews` to a `RelativeLayout` and add a component layout property to your "value" string to always be to the right of the "key" string.

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstText"
```

Comment: I need two columns and left side cannot be set with weight or wrap. Weight could cut text in german language (looong words) and wrap doesn't align right column as it's sticked to left where left one is ending. Or if I'm wrong in understanding your answer, could you provide one example please?

Comment: What do you do if both columns contain really long words? Perhaps I'm not fully understanding what layout you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Plan is to use short ones (like "name", "description", "location" etc) on left side and longer (actual values) on the right side. Something like key/value table. I did tried many different attempts but simply I cannot find good solution so far. It could be one of parent layouts that is responsible for such behaviour but I doubt it because if you select TableRow in android studio you'll see that it's size is correct.

Comment: See my edit. I think that may work like you are hoping. Let me know if you need more of an example.

Comment: I tried your solution as well to see whichone fit me more but the accepted one was the closest to what I already had. Thanks for help thou!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\n` to force a line break

like this:

```
android:text="test test test test\ntest test test test test test test\ntest test test test test test\ntest test test test test"
```

have not tested it now but it should work

... if you want to have it dynamically try:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

on the textview.... but I have not tried it

Comment: This could be solution but not nice one when adding text dynamically. I don't know what I'll have to show there but if you take in account different densities, user text size settings, screen sizes etc. you'll find out that there must be something else I've missed to achieve correct line breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` would work, but if you need it dynamically, then you are thinking that the text should have an specific alignment (justified). There is no way to justify text on Android without 3rd party libraries.

I found some Github libraries some time ago, [here](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) and [here](https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView).